# LINQ query compare DateTime column to DateTime string column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table with 3 columns like below：

```
DeliveryDate(string) | 2020-06-16
DeliveryTime(string) | 20:00:00
EstimateDeliveryDateTime(DateTime) | 2020-06-15 20:00:00.232
```

I wrote below condition in LINQ, expect it convert to sql by ef core, but failed.
`EstimateDeliveryDateTime > Convert.ToDateTime(DeliveryDate + DeliveryTime)`

I know AsEnumberable(). But I want this condition to be executed in db, is it doable in LINQ or not?

Comment: Don't store dates in a database as a string, and you will be golden. also its probably better to combine the date and the time field into one date time. it will make querying a lot easier (in most cases)

Comment: It's a legacy system, I can't update schema.

Comment: Do it with raw sql, where you can convert string into the date. It will not be LINQ, but  you gain nothing by trying to force it via LINQ ;)

Comment: These answers not get my point, it seems I need to change my whole query to use raw sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I create a sql View convert DeliveryDate + DeliveryTime to one DateTime column. And then use ef core keyless entity to query the View.

Answer (score 0):

How about using DateTime.ParseExact?

```
EstimateDeliveryDateTime > DateTime.ParseExact(DeliveryDate + DeliveryTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture")
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: This will not translate into SQL AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

EstimateDeliveryDateTime > Convert.ToDateTime(DeliveryDate + " " + DeliveryTime)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own method/extention method to convert the string to DateTime according to the string format `ie. yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss`.
Here is my suggestion:

**Implementation:**

```
private void Example()
{
    string DeliveryDate = "2020-06-16";
    string DeliveryTime = "20:00:00";
    DateTime EstimateDeliveryDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (EstimateDeliveryDateTime < DeliveryDate.ToDate(DeliveryTime))
    {
        // do something....
    }
}
```

**Extension Method:**

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this string wanabedate, string wanabetime)
{
    try
    {
        string[] mydate = wanabedate.Split('-').ToArray();
        if (mydate == null || mydate.Length < 3)
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }

        string[] mytime = wanabetime.Split(':');

        // create date time
        var year = Convert.ToInt32(mydate[0]);
        var day = Convert.ToInt32(mydate[2]);
        var month = Convert.ToInt32(mydate[1]);

        var seconds = Convert.ToInt32(mytime[2]);
        var mins = Convert.ToInt32(mytime[1]);
        var hr = Convert.ToInt32(mytime[0]);

        DateTime result = new DateTime(year, month, day, hr, mins, seconds, 0);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's issue is that such conversation can not be translated to sql - _expect it convert to sql by ef core,_